# Bootstrap 4 navbar items in container with one item right-aligned out of the container

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have a Bootstrap 4 navbar with a `<div class="container">` wrapped around the navigation links, so the navigation is positioned exactly like the content on my page (which is also in a container)

I now want to add a search input **outside** of the container, aligned to the right side (visible only on XL screens, hidden otherwise)

I know how to align things, I can align it inside the container, but creating another `<ul class="navbar-nav">` outside of the container actually messes everything up, so I'm not really sure how can I do it while also having a container in the navbar.

As far as I can see, it's the fact that `container` has an `auto` margin, and placing a `form-inline` right after the container messaes up the margins, even when using `float-right`

Here's a bootply: https://www.bootply.com/T9Ks167fW7

Comment: So you want the search input where it says "Right-aligned in container"?

Comment: No, if I wanted it there I'd just make it. I want it aligned exactly to the right side of the screen, which needs to go outside the container div but I tried it and it didn't really work

Comment: Post the code in the question itself. The bootply seems to show what's already working. Show the code that's not working so that we understand the problem/question. Do you expect the search input to be aligned to right of the viewport or container?

Answer (score 0):

As for now I went with using a trick to make the inline form use `position: absolute`, this way it doesn't interfere with the margin of `container` so everything looks nice:

```
<form id="search" class="form-inline">
</form>

#search
{
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    margin-right: 1rem;
}
```